# Applying estimated transfer function to a signal

Tags: matlab, filters

This is the simple code to find transfer function between `sigout` and `sigin` signals and then are the filter coefficients estimated by `invfreqz` function.

```
%% load simlated data
load CFDvsABAQUS_TC.mat

%% simulated data preprocessing (grid orientation B)
time = TCb(:,1);
sigin = TCb(:,2);           % inlet temperature (TC signal by Abaqus)
sigout = TCb(:,3);          % outlet temperature (by cfd FENIX)
Fs = 1/mean(diff(time));    % sampling frequency

%% Transfer Function Estimate outlet->inlet
[toi,foi]=tfestimate(sigout,sigin,2^13,[],[],Fs);

%% filter design by known transfer function
w = linspace(0,pi,length(fio)); % angular frequency f=[0,fs/2] -> w=[0,pi]
m = 500; % b coeffs
n = 500; % a coeffs
[boi,aoi] = invfreqz(toi,w,n,m);

%% final Digital filtering
esigin = filter(boi,aoi,sigout);
```

The input data are available at [this dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hj09ktc67mnzs4d/CFDvsABAQUS_TC.mat?dl=0).

The final filter function produce completely wrong results (the result should be similar to original `sigin` signal). I have no idea what is wrong.

Any help will be very useful for me.

Comment: Probably all problems comes from extremely high order m=n=500 at invfreqz function... Some numerical instabilities??? But I need high order estimation to fit properly estimated transfer function.

Answer (score -1):

Your values for `m` and `n` are way too big. Matlab starts getting numerical problems for those values above 30, sometimes.

Try reducing them to more reasonable numbers (e.g. 10) and slowly increase them until `invfreqz` generates bogus outputs.

Comment: Yes, you are right! function "invfreqz" is highly numerical unstable for higher m and/or n values of filter order. I am afraid that this problem has no simple solution...

Comment: @michalkvasnicka Just as a matter of engineering practice, lower-order models that satisfy your requirements are usually better than higher-order models because you end up just using the extra degrees of freedom to fit the noise, not the signal